# trying to collect name

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to collect there first and last name from `responsable`,`president`,`salaries de la fedration` these link http://www.normandie.cuma.fr/fiches/federation-des-cuma-normandie

[image]

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    start_urls = ['http://www.cuma.fr/annuaires?page=1e']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//h2/a/@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        

        name=response.xpath("//article[@class='profile']")
        for names in name:
            first_name=names.xpath("//div[@class='field-item even'][1]//text()").getall()
            last_name=names.xpath("//div[@class='field-item even'][3]//text()").getall()
            yield{
                'first': first_name,
                'last':last_name
                }
```

Comment: of, you are defining a class but never instantiating it. Executing your code does nothing.

Comment: can you help me

Comment: what result are you getting when executing your code?

Comment: they give me empty list

Comment: but your code literally does not instantiate anything. is this all the code you have?

Comment: yes this is my full code

Comment: ok, then it won't work unless you instantiate the class and do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

See the comments for explanation.

```py
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    start_urls = ['http://www.cuma.fr/annuaires?page=1e']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//h2/a/@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        name = response.xpath("//article[@class='profile']")
        for names in name:
            # use relative xpath:  names.xpath('.//div..........')

            # Options 1:
            # I'm using /div/div/text() instead of //text() to avoid whitespace
            first_name = names.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "field-name-field-user-txt-prenom")]/div/div/text()').get(default='').strip()
            last_name = names.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "field-name-field-user-txt-nom")]/div/div/text()').get(default='').strip()

            # Option 2:
            first_name = names.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "field-name-field-user-txt-prenom")]//text()').getall()
            last_name = names.xpath('.//div[contains(@class, "field-name-field-user-txt-nom")]//text()').getall()
            first_name = ''.join(first_name).strip()
            last_name = ''.join(last_name).strip()

            yield{
                'first': first_name,
                'last': last_name
            }
```